# Types annotation that holds string array values

Tags: java

Interface:

```
public @interface Types {
    String[] value();
}
```

Declaration:

```
@Types(TEST.T1, TEST.T2)
public class TEST{
    public static final String T1= "DAS";
    public static final String T2= "ABC";
}
```

How can I class attributes in Types interface correctly?

Comment: *"How can I class attributes in Types interface correctly?"* Define "correctly," and say *specifically* what issue your code has.

Comment: Does your code not compile, does it not do what it is supposed to do, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the curly braces:

```
public @interface Types {
    String[] value();
}

@Types({Test.T1, Test.T2}) // <- requires {} here because multiple values passed
public class Test{
    public static final String T1= "DAS";
    public static final String T2= "ABC";
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Curly_brackets